# Mean frequency and period frequency

Tags: statistics, arithmetic

If I have two frequencies:

$f_1 = 20\text{ Hz}$

$f_2 = 40\text{ Hz}$

the mean between them should be

$$f_\text{mean} =\frac{20+40}{2}=30\text{ Hz}$$

How come that if I calculate their periods' mean

$$\frac{\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{40}}{2} = \frac{3}{80}\neq \frac{1}{f_\text{mean}} $$

the value is different from $1/f_\text{mean}$ ?

Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: You have "$f_1$" appearing twice.  Could you have intended $f_1$ and $f_2$?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going wrong.  There is no reason to think that the average of the reciprocals of a set of numbers is the reciprocal of the averages of the original numbers.  In fact I think since 1/x is convex the Jensen inequality shows that it has to be different.